# En qué modo verbal está el verbo "comer" en la frase "que él coma"

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, imperativo

Según entiendo, el verbo "comer" tiene modo imperativo sólo para los pronombres nosotros, tú/usted y vosotros/ustedes.

Entonces, en qué tiempo verbal está el verbo comer en la frase "que él coma"? Porque parece una orden (imperativo) pero está en uso el tercer pronombre (que supuestamente no tiene conjugación para el modo imperativo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos seguir un proceso de "ingeniería inversa" yendo a la entrada de "[comer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vPNMxG%7C9vRLW2D)" en el diccionario de la RAE.

Cuando la entrada del DRAE es un verbo, aparece ese botón azul que dice "**Conjugar**"

[image]

Y si lo pulsamos vemos las conjugaciones verbales para el verbo "comer". Ahora, si buscamos "*coma*" vemos que es la **conjugación para primera y tercera persona singular de presente de subjuntivo**.

> Mi madre me ha preparado un bocadillo de tortilla para que yo **coma**
>
> Su madre le ha preparado un bocadillo de tortilla para que él (o usted) **coma**

Esas frases en subjuntivo no expresan una orden, si no más bien una sugerencia, petición, deseo o incluso una decisión que depende de alguien a quien se ha dado una orden, que son algunos de los múltiples usos del subjuntivo.

> **Coma** usted ese bocadillo, que le va a sentar muy bien <sub>(Esta es una decisión depende de la persona a quien se dirige un imperativo)</sub>

Y, como bien dices en la pregunta, "*coma*" también es la conjugación de **tercera persona singular de imperativo**

> No **coma** usted tan deprisa, que le va a sentar mal! **Coma** más despacio!
>
> <sub>Nótese que, aunque indistinguibles, el primer *coma* es subjuntivo y el segundo es imperativo. Las órdenes van en imperativo cuando la oración es afirmativa y en subjuntivo cuando la oración es negativa.</sub>

Como sabes el "**[ustedeo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bBiVmX2)**" se usa para refierse a una segunda persona (en plural o singular) pero usa la conjugación de tercera persona.

Además, el modo imperativo no tiene conjugación de tercera persona (salvo porque es necesaria para la forma "usted") porque no puedes darle una orden a alguien sin hablarle directamente (con lo que usarías una conjugación de segunda persona, y no de tercera).

Si tenemos "que **él** coma" entonces estamos seguro frente a la forma de subjuntivo.

Comment: O sea, en "que él coma" estaría dando una orden a una segunda persona, para que ejecute sobre una tercera, usando la tercera persona singular presente de subjuntivo? Entendí bien? O entendí cualquier cosa?

Comment: No estás dando una orden a una segunda persona. "*Hazle/Dile* que se lo coma" le daría una orden a alguien, relativa a una tarea, pero el uso del subjuntivo (que ya sabes que los usos del subjuntivo tienes miga) denotaría que es una sugerencia o que algo depende de quien recibirá (en última instancia) la orden o sugerencia. Pero no necesariamente va a estar relacionado con una orden. Como ves en los ejemplos del bocadillo el uso del subjuntivo expresa **propósito**. No hay ninguna orden de por medio.